# asp.net mvc calling different usercontrol from different view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Have a View Folder

FrontEnd
JobDetails.ascx (View)

Another View Folder
Job
Apply.ascx (view)

I have a Apply (a href) in **jobdetails** which have a show and hide div mechanism for apply (Rendering Apply.ascx in JobDetails

```
 <div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("../../Views/Jobs/Create"); %>
    </div>
```

my create View in job

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Jobs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
```

<% } %>

the question is that how would i go back in the JobDetails View if some Error occurs in my create form to display the errors there . I am at lost here , hope that the question is clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean with "go back"?

Comment: Go back means to the jobdetails view(it is currently picking view based on Jobs/Create) and going to the blank page if some exception occur on pressing create

Comment: blank page means it is showing the exception and the form on the blanks page

Comment: basically create page is rendering in the jobsdetails page which is external to jobdetails page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to handle this is to do the post of the apply via AJAX and simply render the apply form with the errors in place by replacing the existing HTML with that returned when the apply fails.  If javascript is turned off, then it will render just the failed application but that seems like a reasonable trade-off to me.